# Rendering spaces in MHTML email body in SSRS subscription

Tags: reporting-services, sqlreportingservice, ssrs-subscription

I am trying to send a report using SSRS subscription which includes a text with spaces in between as shown in the picture.

The problem is the spaces are ignored and my formatting is disturbed, but when I render as PDF/ WORD format the spaces are perfectly rendered.

How can I preserve the space?

OR

Any other format can help me preserving the space instead of MHTML format in email body.

I want to include the report contents in email body and not as attachment.

[image]

The actual desired format:

[image]

Comment: I am unable to post pictures as of now for the issue..

Comment: I'm quite sure we will be unable to help as of now

Comment: So, why are you unable to post pictures?

Comment: Hey @JamesZ  please check the question for images now

Comment: Is there any reason why the above is not rendered in a tablix with the borders removed and then embedded in MHTML instead of free text with spaces?? It would look so much better inside a tablix design!